# Small model from Google news Word2Vec model

Tags: machine-learning, models, word2vec, gensim

I am using `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` model and [pycontractions](https://github.com/ian-beaver/pycontractions) library to determinate with machine learning the best option to expand contractions when there are ambiguous meanings like `I'd` with can be `I would` and `I had`. The size of this model is very large, around to 3.5Gb.

I think that 3.5Gb is a very large model to use for my purpose. Probably I'll never use all words representations in this model. Is there a way to reduce the size extracting only a subset of words representations that are useful to my purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truncating the set to the 1st N words is easy with an optional argument to `gensim`'s `load_word2vec_format()` method, `limit`. If present, only the given number of words will be loaded. For example, `limit=500000` reads only the 1st 500,000 words from the supplied file.

Since such files are usually sorted to put the most-frequent words first, you often don't lose much by discarding the 'long tail' of later words. (They'll appear less frequently in your texts, and their word-vectors were trained on fewer examples and thus of lower-quality, anyway.)

You could then re-`save_word2vec_format()` the truncated set, if you wanted a smaller file on disk.

You could also tamper with the file on disk to make it only include some *other* subset of words to retain. It might be easier to do so in the text (`binary=False`) format. Looking at the `gensim` source code for `load_word2vec_format()`/`save_word2vec_format()` could help you to understand what the file must look like to read back in.

Comment: Works perfectly, I lose a bit of accuracy but in almost every case the substitution of contractions was perfect.